# How to show record using inner join if one table is empty or row deleted in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have three tables, i use inner join on them and it works fine until i delete one of them.

Here is my code

```
   public function get_complaint($id)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('user u');
        $this->db->join('issue i', 'u.id = i.uid', 'inner');
        $this->db->join('review r', 'u.id = r.complaint_attended_by', 'inner');
        $this->db->join('staff s', 'r.complaint_attended_by = s.id', 'inner');
        $this->db->where('i.id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get()->result_array();
        return $query;
    }
```

Here is query generated from above code

```
SELECT *
FROM `tbl_user` `u`
INNER JOIN `tbl_issue` `i` ON `u`.`id` = `i`.`uid`
INNER JOIN `tbl_review` `r` ON `u`.`id` = `r`.`complaint_attended_by`
INNER JOIN `tbl_staff` `s` ON `r`.`complaint_attended_by` = `s`.`id`
WHERE `i`.`id` = '1'
```

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: have a tried `left join`

Comment: you need to use `left join`

Comment: @James Yes i tried, it also return empty array

Comment: @RobinSingh so which table will not have records more than one or random tables?

Comment: @James random tables

Comment: @James i need record if last table is empty or not

Comment: @RobinSingh can you edit your question by adding sample data result set

Comment: @RobinSingh since your MySQL query is fine share data from all the 3 tables so that what result you are not getting

Comment: @James thanku for your precious time, it works fine now using left join

Comment: @Robin Singh do not forget to rate James thanku  answer. Thank you